# Converting raster file to vector in QGIS takes long time

Tags: qgis, performance, raster-conversion

I am a new user of QGIS, and I am trying to convert a .tif file in a vector.
To do that I have used the "Raster conversion" option, but it is taking a long time. I am waiting 20 minutes for the conversion.

This .tif file is of 1 142 007 Kb.

If this is not normal, is there something that I could do to speed it up?

Comment: You trying to vectorize a 1.1 GB raster ! Obviously this takes time. It depends on your system specifications as well and how you vectorize (burn-values? Attribute Field?). There is no hidden trick to make calculations faster if your computer is slow -_-

Comment: But to reduce time for the conversion Could I use only a part of the raster image? That is i was thinking that I could "cut" only the part interesting of the image and convert only this part in vector.. What you think? is it possible?

Comment: How many unique values are there in the file? If you're trying to vectorize a DEM where each cell has a different value to the surrounding then it's going to take **for ever** to process. Please ensure you're using classified image data for conversion.

Comment: You should definitely clip the file if you are only interested in a part of it. See Raster - Extraction - Clip tool for this