# QGIS 3x GDAL raster to vector (polygonize) option doesn't work

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I want to convert my Geotiff map into the shapefile.

For this purpose, I used the GDAL->Raster Conversion -> Polygonize option.

[image]

I have the status "Processing algorithm" for nearly 2 hours!

I found the similar problem here:

[Long Time for conversion raster file to vector in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95544/long-time-for-conversion-raster-file-to-vector-in-qgis)

but the guy had the file over 1GB. I already clipped my Geotiff map trimming down the size to 30MB.

Why does it take so long then?

Have I missed something?

Or shall I use other options...

[Converting Raster to vector and creating polygons based on each pixel using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294592/converting-raster-to-vector-and-creating-polygons-based-on-each-pixel-using-qgis)

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your raster? How complex is it?

Comment: This is the Ordnance Survey map covering the hamlet. See above